# Is there any measurement of electron spin that doesn't involve magnetic moment?

Tags: electrons, quantum-spin, measurements, magnetic-moment

So the way to measure electron spin is to split the beam with a magnet to obtain two beams. Essentially what gets measured is magnetic moment, that is later interpreted as the direction of spin multiplied by Bohr magneton.

Is there any "direct" measurement of electron spin that ignores magnetic moment?

Comment: What do you mean by "direct"? You put that word "direct" in quotes, does it mean something special to you? Like you want to take a photograph of an electron or something?

Comment: Perhaps there is some angular momentum measurement that doesn't require a magnetic field? Maybe there is some polarization effect in reflected light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electron is also and always a magnetic dipole. Its electric field (its elementary electric charge) is regarded as its outstanding property. If the history of the discovery of the electron had taken a different course, we might have a "magneton" and would regard its magnetic dipole as an outstanding property. All the more so because the deflection in an external magnetic field (Loerenz force), which was initially interpreted as a gyroscopic effect, is based on the interaction with the electron's magnetic dipole.

The spins were postulated based on the observation of the splitting of the spectral lines in a magnetic field. What happens is the alignment of the magnetic dipoles of the electrons of the analysed material in the external magnetic field. Here, too, the interaction between the external magnetic field and the magnetic dipole takes place.

Even if the formalism is so advanced that the spin is considered separately from the magnetic dipole, it is still always based on it. There is no counterexample where this is not the case.